# Known iPhone OS bugs

Tags: ios

Almost all of the time, if there's a bug, it's Your Fault™. But sometimes, it really is a bug in the API/OS. As iPhone OS is relatively new (especially 3.x) there are always a few bugs to look out for.

I think it would be a good idea to compile them in a list. If you know of any, please list them, along with which versions are affected, and if applicable any known workarounds.

It might save someone from pounding their head on their desk out of frustration when they're just experiencing an OS bug.

Comment: To those voting to close this, you don't think it's a good programmer resource to compile a list of OS bugs to look out for?

Comment: This is not really a reliably answerable question. In theory, it sounds like a good idea, but how could a list like this be useful, in practice? What is the criteria for a bug? There's no assurance an answer would reflect a true bug in the system (as opposed to programmer error), nor that answers would be updated when bugs are fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One good resource to look at is open Radar (http://www.openradar.appspot.com)  It is a site where people publicly post the bugs they have filed with Radar (Apple's closed bug tracking system)